# The external activation only starts ssis once

Tags: service-broker, ssis

This was an excellent example and it works well. I have configured this example to start an ssis package using sbea. In testing the package fires, but only once. I know it works because I have the package log to may database when it fires. If I test it again, the package does not fire up.

Whats interesting is that if I end the conversations and purge the queues. Then teardown activation, rebuild it then test again, the package fires and logs to the db.

I modified the easervice config and set the max concurrecny to 4 it makes no difference.

There is only one event in the event viewer and it's from my package and only for the intital package success.
There is nothing added to the easervice log.
And nothing in the sql log.

I am at loss currently and could use some help. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I was able to determine that my issue resided in my recieve syntax within the package itself.
I was not handling the conversation handle correctly so my response was never ending the conversation. It is disappointing however that even with three levels of logging within the package did not log the issue anywhere. I will be reviewing that methodology today.
Cheers